# Coding abstract classes using ndb.PolyModel class from Google Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Is it possible create an abstract class that uses the ndb PolyModel from Google Datastore using Python? I've tried using ABCMeta with no results. Is there any way i can define the SuperFoo class as Abstract?

```
class SuperFoo(polymodel.PolyModel):
   __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
   node_id_int = ndb.IntegerProperty()


class Foo(Foo):
   name_str = ndb.StringProperty()
   category_str = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be declared as abstract?  Instead, how about using standard Python inheritance?

```
class SuperFoo(polymodel.PolyModel):
    node_id_int = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Foo(SuperFoo):
    name_str = ndb.StringProperty()
    category_str = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Comment: SuperFoo doesn't represent a concrete entity in my application but it represent an abstract entity that shouldn't be used by the application.

Comment: Practically, I would initialize SuperFoo only from subclass (in my case from Foo)

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense?? It's my first project with GAE, can you be more specific??

Comment: An abstract class is still used by an application.  It is used (and initialized) through the concrete class.  The methods and attributes (like `node_id_int`) are available to the application.

Answer (score 0):

In java the correct code is:

```
public abstract class SuperFoo {
    ...
}

public class Foo extends SuperFoo {
    ...
}
```

And `new SuperFoo()` doesn't work in the main of the program, but work in the inner of Foo.

How it is possible in Google App Engine ?

In GAE is not possible use `PolyModel` and `ABCMeta` together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by subclassing the two relevant metaclasses: `ndb.MetaModel` and `abc.ABCMeta`.

```
class AbstractMetaModel(abc.ABCMeta, ndb.MetaModel):

  def __init__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
    super(AbstractMetaModel, cls).__init__(name, bases, classdict)
```

Then, set your `SuperFoo`'s `__metaclass__ = AbstractMetaModel`.